# Do xslt 2.0 processors optimize selecting only the first item in a sequence?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, saxon

For example, with the input document:

```
<root b="1" />
```

and the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:variable name="vTest" select="(@a, @b, @c)[1]" />
        <xsl:value-of select="$vTest" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Do XSLT processors optimize by not evaluating the `@c` item in the sequence `(@a, @b, @c)[1]`?

The rational for defining `vTest` this way is to try and emulate `xsl:choose` logic in a shorter way.

I assume this may be difficult to answer generally, I am particularly interesting in Saxon XSLT 2.0 processor versions 9.5+.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saxon will certainly do this optimization. But there's nothing in the spec that guarantees it. And there might be some situations where it doesn't happen, e.g. the execution strategy might be a bit different within a try/catch. But generally yes, most half-way-decent XSLT processors will avoid evaluating EXPR in full when you write EXPR[1].

Comment: Incidentally, a case where it's a bit harder to predict what the XSLT processor will do is if you write `<xsl:variable name="vTest" select="@a, @b, @c" /><xsl:value-of select="$vTest[1]" />`. Even if we know you're using Saxon, the answer to that is going to depend on the exact context.

Comment: Is class `net.sf.saxon.expr.FirstItemExpression` an optimization for specifically the case of form EXPR[1]? Its `evaluateItem` method obtains an iterator for the base expression, gets the first entry and then closes the iterator. So evaluation is only done when called for by getting an entry? Also, does it depend on the transformation source (say, a stream vs DOM)?

Comment: Yes, if the expression is statically of the form EXPR[1] then Saxon will generate a FirstItemExpression at compile time. But even if the predicate is dynamic, e.g. EXPR[$i] where $i has static type xs:integer, Saxon will still only evaluate the first $i items in EXPR. No, it doesn't depend at all on what kind of source it is.